# Azure App Service request takes 120secs, but IIS says it only took 31ms - what's going on?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Our application requests a large object from an upstream server via HTTP and proxies the gzip'ed response to the client. Running the application locally or on a VM on its own leads to a response time of <1s. After deploying to Azure App Service, the request takes ~120s to reach a client as observed using Postman or Chrome. Application-level logging shows that the application is only taking ~25ms and a failed request trace in IIS shows that IIS thinks the request only takes 31ms to serve.

Where are the extra 119-odd seconds being spent? The size of the response is only about 100kB.

Edit: After some investigation it seems that most of the response is sent in <1s, but the last chunk (with size 0, to indicate the end of the response), takes another 119s to be sent, suggesting some sort of timeout.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that we were setting the transfer-encoding header twice in our application by mistake, first with the empty value "" and then "chunked". This must have left IIS confused as to what was the end of the response. Removing the extra header resolved our issue.